# Why is this nameError occurring

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, pygame, nameerror

I am 9 and self teaching, please be kind and keep that in mind when you reply, thank you very much for your time.

I have the image Bluecar.png and the following code in the same file:

```
import pygame, time
pygame.init()
(width, height) = (300, 200)
screen = pygame.display.setmode((width, height))
pygame.display.flip()

player = Bluecar.png
screen.blit(player)
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

But, it causes this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/escape/listings/listings/listing7-2.py", line 7, in <module>
player = Bluecar.png
NameError: name 'Bluecar' is not defined.
```

Also, after fixing the NameError, I think an Attribute Error will occur.

Comment: Well, `Bluecar` *isn't* defined. Did you mean `player = "Bluecar.png"`?

Comment: Then I have a TypeError on screen.blit(player):

Comment: argument 1 must be pygame.surface, not str

Comment: Do you have an image file named `Bluecar.png` you want to use? Presumably, you need some function the will load an image given the `str` name of the file, then *that* would be the first argument to `blit`.

Comment: I have the image file in the same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the `pygame.image.load()` function

```
import pygame, time
import os.path

pygame.init()
(width, height) = (300, 200)
screen = pygame.display.setmode((width, height))
pygame.display.flip()

filepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
x = 0 #x co-ordinate
y = 0 #y co-ordinate
player = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(filepath, "Bluecar.png"))
screen.blit(player, (x, y))
```

**Edit**

Included `os.path.join` to ensure image loaded from the directory of the python file.

Comment: Trying that results in a pygame.error: Couldn't open Bluecar.png. Sorry

Comment: Edited to ensure your image is read from the same directory as your python file.

Comment: screen = pygame.display.setmode((width, height)) has an Attribute error: modulepygame.display has no attribute 'setmode'

Comment: and a blank pygame window (all black)